# How to get time stamps in boot log messages untill the login prompt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, boot

How do I get the time stamps in the bootlog like the following?

```
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.140 2013] U-Boot 1.4.0XXXXXX (Mar 04 2013 - 08:41:02)MPC83XX  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.156 2013]  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.156 2013] Reset Status:  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.156 2013]   
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.156 2013] CPU:   e300c3, MPC8308, Rev: 1.0 at 333.333 MHz, CSB:     133.333 MHz  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.187 2013] Board: XXXXX  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.187 2013] I2C:   ready  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.187 2013] ZDRAM:  256 MiB (DDR2, 32-bit, ECC off, 266.667 MHz)  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.203 2013] ZDRAM Test Started ... DRAM Test Passed.  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.312 2013] ZFlash: 4 MiB  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.312 2013] ZNAND:  512 MiB  
[Tue Mar 19 13:46:28.312 2013] Using default environment  
.  
.  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.640 2013] Jan  1 04:41:28 localhost kernel: device xxxx-1 entered promiscuous mode  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.656 2013] Jan  1 04:41:28 localhost kernel: device xxxx-2 entered promiscuous mode  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.671 2013] Jan  1 04:41:28 localhost kernel: device xxxx-3 entered promiscuous mode  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.687 2013] Jan  1 04:41:28 localhost kernel: device xxxx-4 entered promiscuous mode  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.703 2013] Jan  1 04:41:32 localhost kernel: linux-xxx_port_mode(0, 2)  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.734 2013] Jan  1 04:41:32 localhost kernel: linux-xxx interface [2]  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.750 2013] Jan  1 04:41:48 localhost kernel: xxxx_ioctl(284): xxx.  
[Tue Mar 19 13:49:58.765 2013] root@localhost:/root>
```

How do get the boot log and kernel initialization log till the login prompt?
Some expert has taken the above log in my project for a product earlier.
Can someone help how this needs to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might also look at the kernel config parameter CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME. If you compile the kernel with this support (CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME=y) the kernel will prepend an accurate timestamp to each kernel message that it generates. The output looks like this example:

```
[    2.226780] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    2.227345] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Adding `printk.time=1` to the kernel command line should also enable this without recompiling. On some 2.6 kernels the argument required is simply `time` (and on other earlier ones the feature is not available at all).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [grabserial](http://elinux.org/Grabserial). It will allow you to timestamp every messages coming from the serial line of a booting system. You can even reset the base time matching a string.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the human readable date and time is generating by syslog not by kernel. Normally linux kernel gives you only timestamp since the reboot. You can change the kernel sources and use getnstimeofday() function for it.